# How to divide column table per 10 row data then next data set to the right column in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, mapping, multiple-columns

I am fetching to-do list array data in a useEffect function and now I want to show the results  10 data per column and after showing 10 data in one column the next data will set to the right column.

for example :
I have 22 titles. First 1-10 titles will show in first column then 11-20 titles will show in second column and 21-30 title will show in other column.

arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]

i actually want this output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyCXX.png)

here, is my fethed data and I have tried to show like this. but I can't show 10data per column:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


const Home = () => {

const [collection, setCollection] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            setCollection(json);
            // console.log(json)
        })
}, []);

let modified_collection = [];
if (collection.length > 0) {
    modified_collection = collection.reduce((rows, key, index) => {
        return ((index % 11 !== 10
            ? rows.push([key])
            : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key))
            && rows);
    }, []);
}

console.log(modified_collection);

return (
    <div  >
        {modified_collection.map((row, index) => (
            <div key={index} className='row mt-3'>
                {row.map((col, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="col">
                        <div className='card ' >
                            <p> {col.title}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
}


export default Home
```

Comment: Can you please share your jsx code also with more information and design

Comment: I have edited my question. I tried this code but I didn't get the desired output. I want to show 10data per column. Like if I have 33 titles. First 1-10 titles will show in first column then 11-20 titles will show in second column and 21-30 column will show in other column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple example with appropriate css in order to demonstrate your html

the problem is the splitting of your array.

try this

```
if (collection.length > 0) {
let numberOfColumns = collection.length / 10;

if (collection.length % 10 > 0) {
  numberOfColumns++;
}

let index = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  if (index % numberOfColumns == 0) {
    index = 0;
  }

  if (!modified_collection[index]) {
    modified_collection[index] = [];
  }

  modified_collection[index].push(collection[i]);
  index++;
}
}
```

In the sandbox you can see that it is split correctly

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-3jhwbf?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: hello , thank you for your ans. What you did is 10 columns 20 rows. But I want to show whatever the column number is but each column will show only 10 rows.

Comment: aaa ok sorry i misunderstood it. let me try again

Comment: @RabeyaAktarEty check my updated answer

Comment: ok i am checking.

Comment: @RabeyaAktarEty is this what you want?

Comment: i am sorry that i couldn't tell you actually what output I want. So I have updated my question and attached a picture of the output that actually i want as output.

Comment: yes ok, this is the output that i create in my sandbox.did you check it?

Comment: i checked your sandbox . but it seems like you have wrapped 10rows and some columns in one row. But i want to show individually 1-10 title in one column. then 11-20 title in second column and continue.

Comment: ok i put margin in order to be better shown along with the borders. is it more clear now?

Comment: ow it's now clear. First time i didn't understand as overflow x is not working. so after completing the width others columns showed bellow . that's why I couldn't understand first time. Thank you for your help. Can you plz tell me how can I add overflow  so that after covering the screen size it will overflow horizontally always.

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-3jhwbf?file=/src/index.js

Comment: still horizontal overflow scroll is not working on it. columns are going bellow after covering the full width.

Comment: i see the scroll. weird... check again. i altered the height too

Comment: I have solved the issue. It's working fine now. I just remove flex-wrap from the main div and it's working fine. Thanks a lot for your help .